# How can I share a countDown timer I created with js?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, countdowntimer

I created a countDown timer and it works great. Now what I would like to do is for this event to not refresh if I leave the site and also to share that event... is it possible to do it with js? Or will I have to use NodeJS? I'm sorry that the code is in Spanish. I think I could use localstorage but I've never used it before.

```js
let segundo = 1000,
  minuto = segundo * 60,
  hora = minuto * 60,
  dia = hora * 24;

let btnComenzar = document.querySelector("#comenzar");
let h3 = document.querySelector("h3");

//Generando el evento en base a la fecha actual.
function generarEvento() {
  let fechaEvento = document.querySelector("#fecha").value;
  let evento = new Date(fechaEvento).getTime(); //transformo la fecha ingresada a local time

  setInterval(() => {
    let fechaActual = new Date().getTime();
    //Calculo para llegar a la fecha del evento . 
    let cuentaRegresiva = evento - fechaActual;

    document.querySelector("#dia").innerText = Math.floor(cuentaRegresiva / dia);

    document.querySelector("#hora").innerText = Math.floor((cuentaRegresiva % dia) / hora);

    document.querySelector("#minuto").innerText = Math.floor((cuentaRegresiva % hora) / minuto);

    document.querySelector("#segundo").innerText = Math.floor((cuentaRegresiva % minuto) / segundo);

    //Cuando el contador llega a 0, genero el cartel de llegada/comienzo del evento
    if (cuentaRegresiva < 0) {
      h3.innerHTML = "¡Ha llegado el día!";
      let contador = document.querySelector(".contador");
      contador.style.display = "none"
    };

  });

};

function initApp() {
  //genero el click inicial
  btnComenzar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    h3.innerHTML = ` Su ${document.querySelector("#evento").value} comenzara en:`;
    generarEvento();

  });
}
initApp()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/14/42/04/144204bbc9b0963dddf3efb5e8b62162.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container h1 {
  margin: 50px;
}

h1,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#evento {
  max-width: 290px;
  padding: 5px
}

#fecha {
  width: 130px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 150, 255);
  align-self: start;
}

.btnIcone {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*Seccion invitacion*/

.invitaciones {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.invitaciones {
  display: none;
}

.invitaciones h4 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
}


/*Comienzo del contador*/

.container h3 {
  margin: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li span {
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: block;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px
}

hr {
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
}


/*Segunda parte de la pagina*/

.videoEjemplo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.videoHijo {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

iframe {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 20px;
}

footer span {
  color: aliceblue;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  button {
    align-self: center;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .videoHijo span {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    align-self: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .videoEjemplo {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Font Awsome-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <!--Css propio-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/modal.css">
  <title>Crea tu cuenta regresiva </title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Seccion del modal-->
  <div class="modalBody">
    <div id="miModal" class="modal">
      <div class="contModal">
        <div class="modalHeader">
          <!--header del modal-->
          <span class="cerrar">&times;</span>
          <h2>Aviso</h2>
        </div>
        <!--fin header del modal-->
        <div class="cuerpoModal">
          <!--Cuerpo del modal-->
          <p>Por favor, no deje los campos vacíos.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--Fin "ContModal"-->
    </div>
    <!--Fin de "modal"-->
  </div>
  <!--Fin del modal-->







  <div class="container">
    <h1>Le damos la bienvenida a nuestro sitio donde va a poder crear su propia cuenta regresiva</h1>

    <label for="evento" class="evento">Ingrese el nombre de su evento </label>
    <input type="text" name="evento" id="evento" required><br>
    <label for="fecha">Ingrese la fecha del evento</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>

    <div class="btnIcon">
      <button type="submit" id="comenzar">Comenzar cuenta regresiva</button>
      <i class="fas fa-share-alt"> Compartir evento(proximamente)</i>
    </div>



    <div class="invitaciones">
      <h4> Crear lista de invitados (proximamente)</h4>
      <label for="nombreInvitado">Nombre del invitado: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombreInvitado" id="nombreInvidado">
      <label for="email">Email del invitado: </label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container ">
    <h3>Su evento comenzará en</h3>
    <ul class="contador">
      <li><span id="dia"></span> Días</li>
      <li><span id="hora"></span> Horas</li>
      <li><span id="minuto"></span> Minutos</li>
      <li><span id="segundo"></span> Segundos</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <hr>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Videos desde donde base mi código</h3>
    <div class="videoEjemplo">

      <div class="videoHijo">

        <span>Contador</span>
        <iframe height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4k71G0tPJnA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="videoHijo">
        <span>Modal</span>
        <iframe height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ophW7Ask_0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <span>Creado por Natacha Vergara</span>
  </footer>


  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/modal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Create a little object with all of the initial data (when the user clicks in the "Comenzar cuenta regresiva" button) and store this in a cookie or localstorage. When the page loads, 
 first check to see if there is anything stored in this cookie/ls. If there is then get the values out of your object and pretty much you can create a new function that begins the count down, or fill in the textboxes with their corresponding values and trigger the button click event.

Comment: 80 / 5000
Résultats de traduction
your code is not working under FireFox, and I also found some errors

Comment: Mister Jojo yes, thank you.. the date input doesnt work there..i will solve this error.
Since im new, i think there are a lot of errors..i will be solving them in time.. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to store the initial data (name and date):

```
//Generando el evento en base a la fecha actual.
function generarEvento() {
    let fechaEvento = document.querySelector("#fecha").value;
    let evento = new Date(fechaEvento).getTime();//transformo la fecha ingresada a local time

    setInterval(() => {
        let fechaActual = new Date().getTime();
        //Calculo para llegar a la fecha del evento . 
        let cuentaRegresiva = evento - fechaActual;

        document.querySelector("#dia").innerText = Math.floor(cuentaRegresiva / dia);

        document.querySelector("#hora").innerText = Math.floor((cuentaRegresiva % dia) / hora);

        document.querySelector("#minuto").innerText = Math.floor((cuentaRegresiva % hora) / minuto);

        document.querySelector("#segundo").innerText = Math.floor((cuentaRegresiva % minuto) / segundo);

        //Cuando el contador llega a 0, genero el cartel de llegada/comienzo del evento
        if (cuentaRegresiva < 0) {
            h3.innerHTML = "¡Ha llegado el día!";
            let contador = document.querySelector(".contador");
            contador.style.display = "none"
        };

        var obj = { 
            "name": document.querySelector("#evento").value, 
            "date": fechaEvento
        };
        localStorage.setItem("stored", JSON.stringify(obj));
    });

};
```

These are the relevant lines that changed:

```
var obj = { 
    "name": document.querySelector("#evento").value, 
    "date": fechaEvento
};
localStorage.setItem("stored", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

This creates a tiny JSON object and stores it in the localStorage. Now you just need to check this object when the page load:

```
function initApp() {
    //genero el click inicial
    btnComenzar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        h3.innerHTML = ` Su ${document.querySelector("#evento").value} comenzara en:`;
        generarEvento();
    });

    let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stored"));
    if (obj) {
        document.querySelector("#evento").value = obj.name;
        document.querySelector("#fecha").value = obj.date;
        generarEvento();
    }

}
```

I automatically put the values in the textbox and the date picker elements. Then call the `generarEvento()` function to resume the timer.

If you don't want to use a JSON object you can simply store the date and the name separately, or comma separated (and then split to get them back), or whatever way you wish. Since the object is so small, I don't care about the `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` overhead on load and on save. However, this should give you an idea on how to update the object in the event you eventually decide to provide multiple countDowns instead of just one, simply store an array of your little objects in one single localStorage item.

Comment: Shouldnt stack overflow be in english?
Btw in my country, when we are completely lost at something we say "This is a spanish village to me." xD

Comment: Ha! StackOverflow is in English, and so was OP's question and code, however his site is not, but this shouldn't matter since I believe his question was clear enough :)

Comment: Yep but his and your code is "spanish village to me" :)
Btw I am just curious .. what means that "Ha!"?
In czech we say it like "Ha! I got you! (to a hidden kid)" but that doesnt make sense to me in this context.

Comment: Yes, since im new at coding and this is a proyect for myself to learn, i did it in spanish but i do now i should do it in english the coding part.


Hanlet..it worked!! thank you!! I have something to solve, since it does what i wanted to do i can't create a new event (i think i have to clean cookies or something when the clock ends) but still, i will try to solved it myself but still, thank you again.... have a nice day!

Comment: @DanielČech Ha is just a short laugh (instead of hahahahahaha) :)

Comment: @NatachaVergara I am glad it worked. Good luck with the rest of your learning career.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage save data to object just as
**key: string**, so you may save your date as a string.
Then you may create new Date from that string -> witch create new date object with exact same date.

```js
let d = new Date()
console.log(`original date: ${d.toLocaleDateString()}`)


function saveDate(date) {
    localStorage.myDate = date.toString()
}

function loadDate() {
    // savedDate will be <string> if 'myDate' exists in localStorage, otherwise it will be <undefined>
    const savedDate = localStorage.myDate
    return savedDate ? new Date(savedDate) : null
}


saveDate(d)

//-> date was saved to localStorage as 'myDate': <string>


// now create new date from that string
let d2 = loadDate()

console.log(`loaded date: ${d2.toLocaleDateString()}`)
```

So first thing your timer should do is LOOK if there is any saved date in localStorage and if not do your thing.

```js
let date = loadDate() || `do some other stuff`
```

This will create a date from local storage string (IF there was any) and save it to variable 'date'. If localStorage was empty it will do the thing after **||**

---

If you want to experiment .. when you type to F12 -> console: `localStorage`

... it will show you your localStorage for that domain.
You may clear it by executing `localStorage.clear()`

Comment: Thanks Daniel! i will try this... I've never use local-storage so it will take me some time to make it work with my code..i will let you know when it's working. Have a nice day!

Comment: NP ;) .. remember. localStorage is just "dumb" object that only take strings .. but works like normal object. You just create new **key:value** like with any other object ;) Just the value must be string. If you need for example save object - use JSON.stringify(). Then to load use JSON.parse() ...